# FileNotFoundError: Could not find module (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When trying to import an installed package, I am getting the following error in Jupyter Notebook:

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 
'c:\users\my\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\thundergbm-0.3.16-py3.8.egg\thundergbm\thundergbm.dll' 
(or one of its dependencies). 
Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

The package was installed using the command `python setup.py install` and is recognized as an installed package by Python when running `help('modules')`.

I have read a bunch of similar previous issues and tested the common advice which is to run this command before importing the package but to no success:

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory(r'c:\users\my\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\thundergbm-0.3.16-py3.8.egg\thundergbm)
```

Any ideas what the cause might be and which approaches to take to solve it?

Comment: Did you build `thundergbm` first?  The Python module is just a wrapper.  You need to build the DLL yourself.  https://thundergbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to.html

Comment: Yes. I did build the project file "thundergbm.sln" in Visual Studio. And then ran the command "python setup.py install" , as it was instructed in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that trying to encapsulate your application using a virtual environment. This will prevent the wrong interpreter from being used and avoid import errors.

run in your terminal:

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv 
$ python3 -m venv venv 
$ .\venv\Scripts\activate
$ python3 -m pip install "your package name"
```

After that, you need to run your code using the python interpreter that is inside the venv  package. You can cofigure your IDE or  using the terminal:

```
$ .\venv\Scripts\activate
$ python3 "program name"
```

Comment: It is already installed inside a virtual environment, which is called "tensorflow". You can see that in the path which is "c:\users\my\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\thundergbm-0.3.16-py3.8.egg\thundergbm\thundergbm.dll"

Comment: did you do what @Tim Roberts said?